# Running commands from a file in PDB

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I would like to run a set of python commands from a file in the PDB debugger. 
Related to this, can I set up a file that is automatically run when PDB starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a subclass of `pdb.Pdb` and put a call to your extra stuff in the `__init__`

alternatively

pdb.Pdb() looks for a `.pdbrc` file, so you may be able to put your stuff in there

```
    # Read $HOME/.pdbrc and ./.pdbrc
    self.rcLines = []
    if 'HOME' in os.environ:
        envHome = os.environ['HOME']
        try:
            rcFile = open(os.path.join(envHome, ".pdbrc"))
        except IOError:
            pass
        else:
            for line in rcFile.readlines():
                self.rcLines.append(line)
            rcFile.close()
    try:
        rcFile = open(".pdbrc")
    except IOError:
        pass
    else:
        for line in rcFile.readlines():
            self.rcLines.append(line)
        rcFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pdb contained a bug previously that made this not possible

This has been fixed for python 3.13 and appears to be back ported to 3.11 and 3.12 per the discussion on this pull request

https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/90095#issuecomment-1989517207